# foreign key problem - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

i have this mysql code, but when i delete an element of agrupamento, the child is not deleted in emprego, and it is supposed.

For example i have in agrupamento `- id - 1 || area - science`

and i have in profissao (job) `- ref - 1 || empregoid - 1 || emprego - scientist`

```
 CREATE TABLE agrupamento (  
        id smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,  
        area varchar(30),  
        PRIMARY KEY (id) 
    )

CREATE TABLE emprego (  
    ref int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,  
    empregoid smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,  
    emprego varchar(50),  
    PRIMARY KEY (ref)  
)

    ALTER TABLE emprego  
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_emprego
    FOREIGN KEY (empregoid) REFERENCES agrupamento(id)  
    ON UPDATE CASCADE  
    ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

what is the problem?

(if the area science doesn't exists, the scientist also not.)

thanks!

Comment: What is the kind of table that are you using in your database, certify that the table is innoDB to use FK. In myIsam tables it will not work properly.

Comment: you are correct. i will accept you answer if you want. thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, you are welcome.! Seja Bem Vindo.

Comment: It would be the best if you post the error code from my guess you are using InnoDB as default storage engine for MySQL..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the kind of table that are you using in your database, certify that the table is innoDB to use FK. In myIsam tables it will not work properly.